# Forwarding Apache headers through proxy to Jetty

Tags: apache, proxy, jetty, request-headers

I have this in my Apache conf file:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    SetEnv ntPrincipal "user@domain.com"
    SetEnv legalGivenNames "Me"
    SetEnv legalFamilyName "LastName"
    SetEnv email "user@domain.com"
    SetEnv partyId "123456"
    SetEnv lang "eng"
    #Set Env activeDirectoryGroup "Domain\GroupA"
</IfModule>
```

This enables the following in PHP `$_SERVER['ntPrincipal']`.

The reason for this is to fake similar headers in our local development environments that are automatically injected (via Shibboleth) in our dev/test/prod environments. This works fine for Apache/PHP.

**The problem, my local environment now has to proxy to Jetty (unrelated independent app) and forward those same headers.**

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass /daisy/ http://127.0.0.1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /daisy/ http://127.0.0.1:8888/

ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1 /daisy/

<Location /daisy/>
   ProxyPassReverse /
   SetOutputFilter  proxy-html
   ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8888 /daisy/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap / /daisy/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap  /daisy/ /daisy/
   RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

**Update 1**

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {

    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println(headerName);

    Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaders(headerName);
    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
        System.out.println(headerValue);
    }
}
```

This piece of code lists all headers sent to Jetty. In this case, the headers available in PHP aren't available on Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using that seems to work (both PHP and Jetty see the headers):

```
# PHP Headers
<IfModule headers_module>
        SetEnv ntPrincipal "user@domain.com"
        SetEnv legalGivenNames "user"
        SetEnv legalFamilyName "lname"
        SetEnv email "user.lname@domain.com"
        SetEnv partyId "123456"
        SetEnv lang "eng"
        #Set Env activeDirectoryGroup "domain\group"
</IfModule>

# Daisy Headers
RequestHeader set ntPrincipal "user@domain.com"
RequestHeader set legalGivenNames "user"
RequestHeader set legalFamilyName "lname"
RequestHeader set email "user.lname@domain.com"
RequestHeader set partyId "123456"
RequestHeader set lang "eng"
```